# Upgrading a Raspberry Pi from a deprecated version?

Tags: apt, upgrade, raspberrypi

I've got a raspberry pi that's running 19.10.  On trying to install a new package today, I discovered that this version is deprecated.  How can I upgrade this to 20.04 LTS?

I've tried changing the `ports.ubuntu.com` URLs in sources.list to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` but this doesn't seem to change anything.  `apt update` says this:

```
root@otter:/etc/apt# apt update
Ign:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security InRelease
Err:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`apt-get dist-upgrade` fails with lots of HTTP 404s.  `do-release-upgrade` appears to be doing... something... again, a lot of 404s and eventually it aborts with this:

```
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to 
download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Is there an upgrade path here?  Or am I looking at blowing it all away and starting again?  Really hoping not...

**Edit as requested** Here is sources.list with empty lines and comments removed:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security multiverse
```

Comment: You do not upgrade in place for 19.10 to 20.04 LTS you make live media and do an install.

Comment: @Jos - no, see the question.

Comment: @Bobo - done.  Changing `ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` does seem to get me a successful `apt update` so here's hoping the release upgrade also works.

Comment: @David - really??? The upgrade path from one version of Ubuntu to the next is to blow it all away and start again???  If that's true, it's rubbish.  This isn't a mission-critical device, but it is where I run my work-from-home mirror of a private software repository.  I really don't fancy downloading all 600GB of it again over the crappy VPN (which is why I mirrored it in the first place...)

Comment: You are not going from one to another as an upgrade. An upgrade would be 19.04 to 19.10 or 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS you want to jump to a different path hence re install.

Comment: Why would you lose the 600 GB of data? You of course make a back up first no matter how the new version was being installed. Upgrade or new. You will be offered to replace the existing OS. In MOST cases that does not affect the data.

Comment: @David suggest you read the question before commenting.  I'm upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 - they are consecutive versions.  Or are you suggesting it is never possible to upgrade from a non-LTS version to an LTS version?  If so, dear God, why?

Comment: Made my answer quite clear noting else I can tell you.

Comment: @Bobo - still no joy running `do-release-upgrade`.  404s on URLs such as this: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages

Comment: You missed the window for an online upgrade which is usually up to 3 months after the current release gets EoL status. In your case it ended around July 2020 or before. So, yes, install from scratch, period.

Comment: @Tom did you get his figured out? I'm in the exact same situation. Kind of a pain to install from scratch...

Comment: It seems that installing from scratch is your only option.  I'll get to it any day now...

Comment: I got to it.  Reinstalled from scratch.  It does seem to be the only option.  Thankfully, I'd put /opt and /home on separate partitions.

Comment: Whoever associated this with another question - no, they are more or less completely unrelated.